# Intercept and modify print jobs

Tags: linux, windows, printing, network-printer

I need to apply some modifications (mostly replace some text a la `s/foo/bar/`) to everything that gets printed from a specific Windows application. My guess is that most of the building blocks that can be used for this are already available somewhere. My idea is to proceed as follows:

1. A (fake) network printer is advertized (e.g. from a Linux host)
2. Instead of printing, the communication (in PostScript, say) gets intercepted
3. Things like compression get undone, the result is fed to ...
4. ... a script I write that performs the needed text substitutions
5. The resulting postscript is transmitted to the real printer

Is my idea feasible? And am I right that everything except step 4 should be available from basic tools? If so, could someone shed some lights on how I could really do this? I know too little about the internals of Windows/Linux network printing, CUPS and Samba and whatnot to feel confident how to proceed ...

Comment: If I understand it right, it would be common that the *text* would not be sent to the printer; the *image* of the text would be. So would you also want to use OCR??

Comment: @BenjiWiebe As far as I know PDLs, it is much more efficient to transfer a font description and then transmit the text content (which glyph of which font should be placed where) to the printer than to do the raster-image-processing on your computer and transmit the (resolution-dependant) image data to the printer. So, no, I assume I could get along withoput OCR.

Comment: Oh, I see. OK. Do you not think it would be easiest to work on the client side? On the printing computer? Like all2pdf's virtual PDF printer...

Comment: @BenjiWiebe Hm, you mean print ot PDF, let my script manipulate the PDF, then print the modified PDF? Might be worth a thought (and a try) ...

Comment: Not necessarily that (though that might work)...I was suggesting that you create a "virtual printer" to do that (which would require programming skills, but it doesn't seem like there is an already existing program to do what you want done).

Comment: Hi, I have a similar issue. Were you successful? If so, how did you manage it?